# Is func_globals mutable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) states:

> `__globals__` `func_globals`
>
> A reference to the dictionary that holds the function’s global variables — the global namespace of the module in which the function was defined.
>
> Read-only

However modifying that dictionary works just fine. Does the mentioned `Read-only` property exclude immutability?

Comment: In 2.7.6 I can change both `__globals__` and `func_globals` (and `foo.func_globals is foo.__globals__`). Could you provide an example that demonstrates the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I messed things up a bit. I tested assigning as well as setting values. While the latter works fine with both attributes the first one works with neither. I will thus change my question and ask whether the mentioned read-only excludes immutable.

Comment: You get a reference to a dictionary, which is mutable. You can't reassign (e.g. `foo.func_globals = {}`), but you can alter its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that `func.func_globals` and `func.__globals__` are two references to the same thing:

> *Changed in version 2.6*: The double-underscore attributes `__closure__`, `__code__`, `__defaults__`, and `__globals__` were introduced as aliases for the corresponding `func_*` attributes for forwards compatibility with Python 3.

In other words:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
    pass

>>> foo.__globals__ is foo.func_globals
True
```

When they are referred to as "read-only" attributes, this is because you cannot reassign the attribute:

```
>>> foo.__globals__ = {}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    foo.__globals__ = {}
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

However, the object returned *is mutable*, as it's a dictionary. Therefore you *can* add keys to the dictionary and remove them from it (although I would recommend against removing any until you're sure you know what you're doing!):

```
>>> foo.func_globals
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 
 '__package__': None, 
 '__name__': '__main__', 
 'foo': <function foo at 0x02ED15F0>, 
 '__doc__': None}
>>> foo.func_globals['bar'] = 'baz'
>>> del foo.func_globals['__doc__']
>>> foo.func_globals
{'bar': 'baz', 
 '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 
 '__package__': None, 
 '__name__': '__main__', 
 'foo': <function foo at 0x02ED15F0>}
```